# Content-type application/json causes 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am testing Forge API, and I have been able to complete requests smoothly for most endpoints, except the GET Hubs - I kept getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Strangely enough, after I remove the Content-Type header - which was the same header used for all the other end-points of `Content-Type:application/json` - 
the request worked and returns a 200 with the correct data.

Is there something about content-type I am not familiar with? 
Shouldn't the first request work?

Request 1 - Returns 415 for hubs endpoint: no data

```
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Request 2 - Returns 200: data ok

```
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

[image: Request 1]
[image: Request 2]

Comment: You don't need to pass content-type to make request to GET apis. Only POST or PUT apis would need that to indicate the format of the payload.

Comment: Of course. Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I guess I got confused because some of the other GET methods went through with the header, so I just assumed needed to send it.

Comment: GET APIs should normally ignore the content-type headers even if they are passed. The issue is reported to the API team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the comments (thanks @chetan-ranpariya)

1. You don't need to pass a Content-type on GET requests
2. the API should ignore the header; issue has been reported to API team

Answer (score 2):

The [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/) defines that the client MUST send `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is entirely correct if you look at the [request examples](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-resources) it would seem the `Content-Type` is not necessary. The [Content Negotiation](https://jsonapi.org/format/#content-negotiation) requirement seems to contradict the request examples.